# camera2 createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession doesn't work on samsung s9

Tags: android, android-camera2

When I try create HighSpeedCaptureSession on samsung S9:

```
 mCameraDevice.createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession(surfaces, stateCallback , mBackgroundHandler);
```

I get exception:
CAMERA_ERROR (3): endConfigure:442: Camera 0: Error configuring streams: Broken pipe (-32)

On S8 it works fine.

Also I have tried another apps with HighSpeedCaptureSession, it doesn't works on S9 too.

Comment: I have heard from next update of binary this error will be resolved...